# tf Iris - how to avoid warning message on deprecated estimator

Tags: tensorflow, deprecated, iris-recognition

Just started on tf. When running the Iris example, I ran into this
warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <...>/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py:348 
in predict.: calling BaseEstimator.predict (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with as_iterable is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.

"Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn."
```

I installed tf in Feb 2017 (after API 1.0 release). So, I am not sure why this 
warning is popping up.

The code ran correctly, though.

I would like to know:

- is the issue in tf library, or, in python base (anaconda 3.5)?
- how to avoid it?

Even though it is just a warning now, it might create hard-to-find problems later, and would like to address it early, when i'm still on the learning curve.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this warning is being generated by the TensorFlow library `tf.contrib.learn.estimator.py`.  This warning appears to have been added on 2016-12-01 when the decision was made to drop support for `x=` and `y=` in favor of the `input_fn=` parameter to `BaseEstimator`.  Based on the comments made by Martin Wicke during the [TensorFlow Dev Summit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t64ortpgS-E&index=6&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKGc_NBoIhTn2Qhraji53cv), all the procedures in `tf.contrib` are subject to change up until the point they are moved into TensorFlow Core.  He also stated that the previous interface would be supported by SKEstimator.  The Google team has done a great job of keeping the tutorials up todate.  The stated plan is to move Estimators into TensorFlow Core in the next few months.